# What should I do if I don't get a sufficient answer?

Tags: support, bounty

I have a small problem, recently I have asked a question about [Cassel's statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97655/local-global-principle-and-the-cassels-statement) and after waiting for many days, I have decided to keep a bounty. And atlast one day I have received a considerably good answer from Prof.Franz Lemmermeyer. His answer served in providing a beautiful reference.

But its after much strenuous efforts, at-last I got a photo-copy of the Appendix-B. It in-fact contains a brief summary about Tamagawa Numbers, but it didn't give a clear description about the exact point I was asking for ( I mean how can tamagawa numbers, serve as a modern-reformulation of Local-Global Principle for genus-0 curves in terms of quantitative measure ) .

So I am saying that there might be a clear information present in that paper, but it is not complete in this context. Is there any way that some one just post a brief gist about my question ? . I think even a whole topic can be given a brief description. I mean one can paraphrase the entire complex thing into a paragraph in a elegant manner just giving some description.

Like there was a fantastic attempt done by Prof.Matthew Emerton in answering a similar question regarding a reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83422/reading-the-mind-of-prof-john-coates-motive-behind-his-statement) . He has posted a very long and an elegant explanation. But I think not all times I can expect such a beautiful answer. And that too now-a-days Prof.Emerton, seems to be so busy in his work, so its not fair to again start a meta topic.

So main purpose of opening this meta topic is that , Can I again keep a bounty for the same question asking to give a clear reference. I wanted to ask this at the comments section present at the question, but later I understood that its not fair on my part to disturb a good mathematician like Prof.Franz Lemmermeyer to answer my question leaving all his work. ( In that case I mustn't have disturbed another seminal mathematician like Prof.Emerton , but I am having a small hope , a small confidence that he might answer one day or the other ) . So I am making this attempt.

> So Please answer me one thing, Is there any way to again keep a bounty for a question, which already had a bounty ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there can only be one *active* bounty for a question at any given time, a user can have up to three active bounties (for three different questions) at any given time, and there is no limit to the total number of bounties placed on a question through its history or the total number of bounties opened by a user (except the necessary constraint that each time you open a bounty you lose some reputation points).

Other than that, there is the rule that **if a user chooses to open multiple bounties on the same question, each successive bounty will cost twice as much reputation than the previous one**. To read about this and various other rules and conventions on bounty-setting, please see [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/).

If you do set another bounty on the same question, you may want to make use of the additional custom text to specify why you feel that another bounty is necessary for the same question. (Namely, you should condense much of what you wrote in the statement for *this* Meta question into a bounty notice for the bounty you set.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, It was very useful for me, you have been answering my doubts from the beginning and I extend my unparalleled gratitude towards you . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Iyengar, I know English isn't your first language, but when you say that your gratitude is unparalleled you're implying that anyone else's gratitude pales in comparison to yours... which is weird.

Comment: @UnreasonableSin : I am extremely sorry, for my hopeless language, neither I know proper english, nor I know about this technology, as I am from a remote part which is unsophisticated. So I am improving day by day, with the suggestions, Hope one day I can speak good english. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.